GPUParticles3D Godot use multiple mesh textures
I have a GPUParticles3D that produces meshes with a single texture. I'm thinking if I'd make the texture a ShaderMaterial and apply a shader, I could in theory make each particle have a different texture with an array of textures. If there's an easier way to do this I'm open to ideas, but I've not been able to find it after a few days of searching. I suppose one work around would be to have multiple GPUParticles3D each with their own texture, but I really believe this should be able to be done by a texture.
shader_type spatial; 
uniform sampler2D text[15]; 
uniform int index;

void fragment() 
{ 
    ALBEDO = texture(text[index],UV).rgb; 
} 

So currently the int uniform index is always zero, but I'm thinking if I can pass something to the particle, even a random hash I could set the uniform. Is there anyway to do this or seed it myself from the GPUParticles3D?
I'll mention I am pretty new to shaders, so maybe this isn't possible? If there's a way to accomplish this in Godot it'd be great to know about!
TIA.
